# Memory Leak During Push In A Queue

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, queue

I been working in a project for my Data Networks course and I encounter a memory leak but I don't understand why it's happening.

By the way, I know there is a awful mix of C and C++, but I can't do anything about it, it's based on class code and I can't modified that, I know that this is not a good way to do it and I need to use char* as requisite.

My program it's multithreaded and I handle this struct:

```
typedef struct packetQueue
{
    char* buf;
    int length;

    packetQueue()
    {
        buf = nullptr;
        length = 0;
    }

    packetQueue(char* buffer, int len)
    {
        length = len;
        buf = new char[length + 1];
        memcpy(buf, buffer, len);
        buf[length] = '\0';
    }

    packetQueue(const packetQueue& other)
    {
        length = other.length;

        if (other.buf)
        {
            buf = new char[length + 1];
            memcpy(buf, other.buf, length);
            buf[length] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            buf = nullptr;
        }
    }

    packetQueue& operator=(const packetQueue& that)
    {
        if (this == &that)
        {
            return *this;
        }

        delete[] buf;

        length = that.length;

        if (that.buf)
        {
            buf = new char[length + 1];
            memcpy(buf, that.buf, length);
            buf[length] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            buf = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~packetQueue()
    {
        delete[] buf;
        buf = nullptr;
    }

} PACKET;
```

In my constructor with two parameters I do that assignment because the push of my queue does a deep copy of my struct and like I have my copy constructor and I already handled that. So, I have one thread (I been testing one by one, and the VLD results are just for this one).

```
DWORD _stdcall PHY_in_Thread(void* data)
{
    int numbytes, counter = 0;

    SOCKET hostSocket = *(SOCKET*) data; // Socket where the host receives

    struct sockaddr_in si_recvfrom;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t addr_len;

    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;

    while ( 1 )
{
    char* recBuf = new char[BUFLEN + 1];
    // Checks if it's any buffer on the socket to be processed
    if ( (numbytes = recvfrom(hostSocket, recBuf, BUFLEN, 0, (sockaddr*) &si_recvfrom, &addr_len)) == -1)
    {
        cerr << "Could not receive datagram." << endl;
        delete[] recBuf;
        closesocket(hostSocket);            
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }
    recBuf[numbytes] = '\0'; // append NULL to the end of the string

    char* temporalBuffer = new char[numbytes - CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE + 1];
    memcpy(temporalBuffer, recBuf, numbytes - CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE);
    temporalBuffer[numbytes - CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE] = '\0';

    char extractedChecksum[CHECKSUM_HEX_SIZE + 1];
    DWORD crcBuffer = crc32buf(temporalBuffer, numbytes- CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE); // Calculates the CRC32 checksum
    _snprintf(extractedChecksum, 8 , "%08lX", crcBuffer); // Prints the string in a buffer
    extractedChecksum[CHECKSUM_HEX_SIZE] = '\0';

    delete[] temporalBuffer;

    string strExtractedChecksum = extractedChecksum; // Copies the array in a string
    transform(strExtractedChecksum.begin(), strExtractedChecksum.end(), strExtractedChecksum.begin(), upper); // Uppercase the string

    // Array for store the checksum of the packet
    char readChecksum[CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE + 1];

    // Store the checksum of the packet in local variable
    memcpy( readChecksum, &recBuf[numbytes - CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE], CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE);    
    readChecksum[CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE] = '\0';

    std::stringstream stream;
    string strReadChecksum;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHECKSUM_MAX_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        int number = static_cast<int>(readChecksum[i]); // Casts every character of the checksum array

        if ( readChecksum[i] <= -1 ) // In case the int value it's negative adds the constant value to make that recognizable
        {
            number += 256;
        }

        // Convert the decimal number in a hex representation
        stream.str("");
        stream << hex << number;

        if ( stream.str().length() < 2 ) // In case it's a number less than 10, adds a 0 at the beginning
        {
            strReadChecksum += "0" +  stream.str();
        }
        else
        {
            // Working out the presentation of the number
            strReadChecksum += stream.str();
        }
    }

    std::transform(strReadChecksum.begin(), strReadChecksum.end(), strReadChecksum.begin(), upper); // Uppercase the string
    strReadChecksum[CHECKSUM_HEX_SIZE] = '\0';

    cout << "[PI] Frame #" << counter <<" received ("<< numbytes <<" bytes). " << endl;
    if ( !strcmp(strReadChecksum.c_str(), extractedChecksum) ) // Checks if the CRC are equal
    {
        cout << "[CRC] Checksum OK: 0x" << extractedChecksum << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "[CRC] Checksum failure: 0x" << extractedChecksum << endl;
    }

    // Push the packet in the MAC_in_queue to be processed
    MAC_in_queue.push(PACKET(recBuf, numbytes));
    recBuf = nullptr;
    counter++;

            break;   // Just for test one packet
}

MAC_in_queue.clear();

return 0;
```

}

But when I execute this thread and send something to this thread to be stored in this queue gives a leak. In this execution there is only one item to make things simple.

```
---------- Block 29 at 0x0068F718: 264 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\concurrent_queue.h (402): Host.exe!Concurrency::concurrent_queue<packetQueue,std::allocator<packetQueue> >::_Allocate_page + 0xF bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\concurrent_queue.cpp (113): MSVCP110D.dll!Concurrency::details::_Micro_queue::_Push + 0xD bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\concurrent_queue.cpp (240): MSVCP110D.dll!Concurrency::details::_Concurrent_queue_base_v4::_Internal_move_push
    d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\concurrent_queue.h (581): Host.exe!Concurrency::concurrent_queue<packetQueue,std::allocator<packetQueue> >::push + 0xF bytes
    d:\users\silex rpr\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project3\hoster\host.cpp (638): Host.exe!PHY_in_Thread + 0x3D bytes
    0x7474339A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x76EC9EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
    0x76EC9EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    01 00 00 00    60 F8 68 00    80 00 00 00     ........ `.h.....
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
```

But I don't understand where it's this data leaking, I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks beforehand

Comment: What do the `push` and `clear` methods do?  Well ... I can guess what they are supposed to do, but it kind of looks like the leak is in the push method (as if the clear is maybe not clearing the queue).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the concurrent_queue of Visual Studio 2012, but that clear it's outside of my loop so when the thread ends, clean up all the data, but even doing that it keeps sending me that leak.

Comment: You should add an assignment operator to `PACKET` because you can't risk the implicit one copying the `buf` pointer leading to a double free.

Comment: Yes, I already add one and the error it's exactly the same.

Comment: Is there other thread that call `MAC_in_queue.try_pop()` concurrently?　If yes, it may cause undefined behavior because `concurrent_queue::clear` is NOT concurrency-safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the beginning of `while ( 1 )` loop in `PHY_in_Thread()` you allocate `recBuf`:

```
char* recBuf = new char[BUFLEN + 1];
```

but at the end of the loop body, you miss to free it; you just leak the memory due to 
`recBuf = nullptr;` assignment.

Instead, try with proper `recBuf` deletion at the end of loop body:

```
delete [] recBuf;
recBuf = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment operator does not free the old contents in the PACKET before allocating the copy of "that."  So if you overwrite an entry in some container code, the buffer held by the over-written item would leak.  That's a leak, but of course I can't prove it is the leak that you are seeing.

Comment: I just did that in my function and I put a breakpoint in the first line of my assignment operator but it never goes there, it never break in that point and the leak keeps happening

Comment: looks like you changed your code, now I would say the leak is exactly what @Mr.C64 says above, you never clean up the original buffer "recBuf", since you are missing the call to

    delete [] recBuf;

Comment: to clarify: as your code stands now, you construct a temporary PACKET from recBuf, which makes a copy of the buffer in the constructor from buffer+len.  Provided the container classes (queue) you use are correct, this will be further copied and those copies freed later.  The temporary PACKET you created frees its buffer copy when it destructs immediately after the call to "push(...)" returns.   But the original "recBuf" is never freed in the success case.

Answer (score 1):

you have allocated recBuf in the beginning of the while(1) loop with this command:

```
char* recBuf = new char[BUFLEN + 1];
```

then you pass it to a temp variable PACKET(recBuf, numbytes) which will live only for the scope of one line of code:

```
MAC_in_queue.push(PACKET(recBuf, numbytes));
```

now, assume that MAC_in_queue initialised like this:

```
concurrent_queue<PACKET> MAC_in_queue
```

This means that you will be using a copy constructor and operator= at the same time. Because you do not free the memory allocated for buf in either of this commands, you have a leak.

Please read [this article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/) that has an example similar to yours. See how they implemented Copy constructor and operator =

Comment: I just did that in my function and I put a breakpoint in the first line of my assignment operator but it never goes there, it never break in that point and the leak keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your packetQueue is not doing much (apart memory management, that is not working properly).

You could implement your class using a standard container. Assuming that you do not want a reference counting implementation of your class we need to rule-out std::string, but you could use std::vector. For example:

```
class PacketQueue
{
public:
    PacketQueue() : buf_() {}
    PacketQueue(char* buffer, int len) : buf_(buffer,buffer + len) {}
    //here your function to return the '\0' terminated buffer
    //and all the other stuff that you need
private:
    std::vector<char> buf_;
};
```

Please note, the default: copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor are ok, you do not need to implement anything of that. Basically the memory management is encapsulated into std::vector.

Also this is strong exception safe guarantee. Your code is not.

Comment: Of course in modern C++ we could use `std::vector` and be happy with it. But read the question: _"By the way, I know there is a awful mix of C and C++, but I can't do anything about it, it's based on class code and I can't modified that, I know that this is not a good way to do it and I need to use char* as requisite."_

Comment: you are not saying anywhere that you cannot use standard container. Also you mentioned that you cannot change a class, but I assumed it wasn't PacketQueue because you added the assignment operator to it. In your code you use string (std::string?) and std::transform, so I thought you have access to std::vector as well. Are you the owner of  packetQueue? Can you use standard container?

Comment: This is something the OP should clarify. If he _can_ use `std::vector` and modern C++ and drop raw-C-style, then there are several points of improvements, including some `new[]`'s in the body of the thread function (e.g. `recBuf`, `temporalBuffer`), that can be updated using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest what others before me.
The leak is in your while loop, allocating recBuf but there is no appropiate delete for it.
In details:

```
//Allocates memory,ok
char* recBuf = new char[BUFLEN + 1];

//free memory when exits, ok
if ( (numbytes = recvfrom(...)) == -1)
{
    cerr << "Could not receive datagram." << endl;
    delete[] recBuf;
    ...
}

//do something with it

//And here is the problem
MAC_in_queue.push(PACKET(recBuf, numbytes));
//With this you call this constructor
// packetQueue(char* buffer, int len)
// which allocates the same amount of memory, and copies the contents of recBuf
//So, there is a +1 memory allocation

// This is not deallocate memory :)
recBuf = nullptr;
```

I suggest to move the recBuf memory allocation outside of the loop, and delete it at the end( with delete[] recBuf )

```
delete[] recBuf;
MAC_in_queue.clear();
```

, with this, you don't allocate needlesly every time,therefore making it somewhat faster.
Or if you prefer this way, you should insert a code like this:

```
 delete[] recBuf;
 recBuf = nullptr;
```